# improve the performance of Curvature Filter

Tags: image, opencv, filter

I developed some image filters, named curvature filter, and the source code is [here](https://github.com/YuanhaoGong/CurvatureFilter). I spent a lot of time in optimizing the code and try to make it faster. But my programming experience is limited and I believe that there still is some improvement for this code.

I kindly invited you to run the code and inform me which part of the code that you think could be improved. I would appreciate it! Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ this site is better for this kind of questions

Comment: thanks! I also put the message there! Thanks for pointing it out!